# Change font icon color inside button on hover

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

In the footer of my site (in development) http://www.stefaanoyen.be, there are 3 buttons with an arrow before the text. The arrow is an icon font, and I want it to change color (as does the button text) when the button is hovered.

Any idea how to do this?

**This is my html:**

```
<a class="footerbutton"><span class="footerlist">X</span>Vraag offerte</a>
```

**This is the button:hover css:**

```
a:hover.footerbutton {
background-color: #B61618;
color: #ddd;
border: none;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

**And this is the footerlist span class css:**

```
.footerlist:hover {
color: #ddd;
 }
```

Comment: So the arrow should change if button hovered?

Comment: just put the arrow into the span with Vrag offerte

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to target the icon's color inside the button on hover would be to target it like such:

```
.footerButton:hover .footerlist {
   color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: @Stefaan Great to hear! Feel free to upvote/accept answer if it worked :) glad it worked

Comment: How would you change the color of the buttons background if you did the hover like so and still maintain changing the icons color?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
a:hover.footerbutton:hover .footerlist {
    color: #ddd;
}
```